# Xamarin android build failed

Tags: java, android, xamarin.forms

I tried to run basic Xamarin.Forms application on my device (Android 7.1) and got the following error:

> error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code -1073740791.

How to fix this error, or just figure out what't wrong? Multi-Dex flag is enabled. Java version: 1.8.0_131

Full build log:

```
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code -1073740791.
```

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit version of java installed?  http://motzcod.es/post/157589380047/xamarin-cycle-9-preparing-machines

Comment: Yes, i have x64

Comment: There are sometimes more clues in the output near the error message. If you're using Visual Studio, look in the Output window, not the Error window.

Comment: see the question - i added build log

Comment: Did you update your Android SDK? Or made any changes in it?

Comment: i have the latest version of SDK and no changes are made

Comment: Maybe try increasing your Java Max Heap Size in VS under your android project  properties > android options > advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android sdk reinstallation resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Android SDK version is latest and all the Build Tools are updated.

Another important fact to look at is the version of Proguard in your android-sdk folder, because Google no longer updates Proguard with Android SDK.

So the solution is to update your proguard version manually.

Download the latest version from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/

Extact it, and replace the new proguard folder with the old proguard folder in [sdkpath]/tools/proguard

It is suggested to make the backup of the old proguard folder by renaming it into something like proguard-old, and copying the new proguard5.3.3 folder as proguard.

Comment: Can you try MutliDex Disabled, What output do you get?

Comment: the same, i also tried to chose another devices (emulated) and got the same error

Comment: Please share your complete Build output, in pastebin or as gist

Answer (score 0):

How about try Change Java Max Heap Size to 1G?

Comment: Not sure this will fix or not, how about the path at the Enviroment Variables? C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: Yes, i have this line